# I don't think my /home partition is being used for home

Tags: root, home-directory, disk-usage, user-space

My root partition is running out of space and it doesn't add up as I haven't been installing more than a few hundred MB

When I open disk usage analyzer it says home is taking up a lot of space and shows it as being under root.
When I open gparted I can see that there's some data on my /home partition.

Can someone help me figure this out?  Searching is leading me round in circles

Comment: Do you actually have a /home *partition*? You could tell by running `df -hl`

Comment: Check fstab to see if you are mounting a /home partition. `cat /etc/fstab` and `mount` to see if correctly mounted.

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda3       211G  9.7G  191G   5% /home

9.7g shows some usage (install two weeks old)

cat /etc/fstab - shows a /home used during installation

Answer (score 0):

df -hl
and
cat /etc/fstab

Did let me know it was being used and I was able to solve my root space problem by using gparted to grow my root partition